# Eclipse Development IDE with Tomcat - Using external Tomcat binaries with separate CATALINA_BASE

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to configure Eclipse to use a CATALINA_BASE that is different from the CATALINA_HOME. I know how to configure eclipse to use an externally installed Tomcat (outside of eclipse), but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to repeatedly configure it to use an external set of configuration files (server.xml, catalina.properties, etc.) that are not part of Eclipse OR the installed binaries.

I prefer to have my CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE be seperate.

Any help would be awesome!

Thank you,

Comment: What does each value represent?

Comment: It is fairly straight forward, actually Tomcat has very good documentation on it. Refer: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/introduction.html#CATALINA_HOME_and_CATALINA_BASE

Comment: Isn't this what it already does? Otherwise, wouldn't you set those environment variables yourself when using the catalina scripts, as described in the `RUNNING.txt`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. Yes, I am fully aware of the documentation from Apache Tomcat, however Eclipse doesn't seem to allow for this much. Getting it to pay attention to a separate CATALINA_BASE is troublesome, it seems to insist that the 2 variables, HOME and BASE be the same value. I want these to be different paths all together and I want Eclips to do all the Eclips stuff like deploy, etc. to use the CATALINA_BASE settings.